# Sum of Chebyshev Polynomials of the 2nd kind

Tags: trigonometry, chebyshev-polynomials

I am attempting to simplify the following summation and would appreciate being pointed in the correct direction on how to do this, or if even possible. When I say simplify, I specifically mean removing the summation, in a manner similar to [Lagrange Trig Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange%27s_trigonometric_identities).

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n/2-1} \frac{\sin((2x+1)\frac{\pi} {n} k))} {\sin(\frac{\pi} {n} k)}$$
Where:

- $n$ is an integer power of $2$ such that $n \geq 4$ (so the summation's upper limit makes sense): ${4,8,16,32,...}$
- $x$ is a non-negative integer: ${0,1,2, 3,...}$

What I have tried:

$f(x)$ can be rewritten in terms of Chebyshev Polynomials of the 2nd kind.

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n/2-1} U_{2x}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}k)) = \sum_{k=1}^{n/2-1} U_{2x}(\sin( \frac{\pi}{n}k) )$$

P.S. The $\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}k)$ can be changed to $\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}k)$ above if you consider expanding the summation in the opposite order (from $n/2-1$ to $1$). Happy to explain more on this if unclear.

I then substituted the summation form of [Chebyshev Polynomials of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html) (Eq 16) in the hope that reordering the summations might yield something useful but that seemed to not simplify further.

To summarise, the question is: How can I simplify the following so that the summation sign can be removed (in a Lagrange Trig Identity fashion)?

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n/2-1} \frac{\sin((2x+1)\frac{\pi}{n}k))} {\sin(\frac{\pi} {n} k)}= \sum_{k=1}^{n/2-1} U_{2x}(\cos( \frac{\pi}{n}k) ) = \sum_{k=1}^{n/2-1} U_{2x}(\sin( \frac{\pi}{n}k) )$$

Other notes:

- Perhaps the fact that $(2x+1)$ is always odd and $n$ is always a power of 2 is helpful.

Comment: Warning: you can loose a lot of time attempting to find closed-form formulas that probably don't exist... A question: why are you interested in finding such a closed form formula ?

Comment: A little detail : index $i$ should be replaced by $k$ in the last formula.

Comment: Index corrected.

Comment: Closed Loop Form needed to optimise software which takes too long to run. This post has a “similar” concept but with a fixed argument and varying Chebyshev Polynomial which may be useful. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427585/resultant-of-linear-combinations-of-chebyshev-polynomials-of-the-second-kind 
I realise what I am asking for is a fixed Chebyshev Polynomial and changing argument but it may be useful.

Comment: Any hints from anyone?